# How to keep scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to set scrollview. How to do this?

In my Listview i have 10 items to view..Im can see only 7items..Remanining 3 items I need a scrollview to see..Any possible is there to keep scrollview..Please guide me..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Nexttopic" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
     </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> ```
>     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>       viewList = Nexttopic.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_nexttopic, null);
>       dialogMarketList = new Dialog(Nexttopic.this);
>       dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>       dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);
>       dialogMarketList.show();     
>       lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.List_view);
>       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(Nexttopic.this, R.layout.row_topic, R.id.child_row,tnamelist));
>       lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

Comment: What does mean "Keep ScrollView"?

Comment: @artemzinnatullin I have 10 items in listview, it shows 7items only, i want to scroll for to see remaining 3 items, i can't able to scroll..please guide me..

Answer (score 1):

scrollview for what reason? you have listview just set the height as match_parent and it will take care itself for scrolling item

Use this layout instead of using scrollview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Nexttopic" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In Listview i have 10 items its not scrolling, i can't see the scroll...

Comment: post your activity code in question

Comment: see my code..in question

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use something called :[Google](http://www.google.com)
sorry for my last answer .Read this: Listview so have inbuild scrolling capabilities. Encapsulate it in any other layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.If you still have problems show some of ur code.

```
EDIT:
```

Dont know but try this

```
          listview.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```

Comment: I can't able to scroll...

Comment: how to keep scroll view to list view..

Comment: List view is provided with its own default scrollView!!

Comment: That i can't able to scroll...please  guide me frnd..

Comment: See the Edit try using that may be that works..!

Comment: No it also doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

No need to put scrollview for the listview. it will automatically scroll depending on numbers of row in the listview.

Comment: No I can't able to scroll